# Mypy Flycheck Clears Errors On Unsaved File

Tags: emacs, mypy, lint, language-server-protocol, flycheck

I am currently trying to port over my python enviornment to Doom Emacs from VSCode. One of the major features I want is type checking from `MyPy`. Doom Emacs' flycheck comes with `MyPy` as an option by default so I was going to use that.

My major issue with it though is that while it correctly lints saved files, as soon as I make any edits all linting help goes away and mypy will say that there are no errors until the next time I save. It would be okay if the linting didn't re run while I was editing, but its important for me that the errors don't just disappear.

Notably, when I use other checkers, such as `flake` or the default `lsp`, there is no such issue with linting disappear.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Not a Doom Emacs user, but it sounds like it might be setting [`flycheck-check-syntax-automatically`](https://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/user/syntax-checks.html#variable-flycheck-check-syntax-automatically). Disable Doom's setting or customize it yourself to include "idle-change". For instance mine is (via `C-h v flycheck-check-syntax-automatically`):

```
flycheck-check-syntax-automatically is a variable defined in ‘flycheck.el’.

Its value is (save idle-change new-line mode-enabled)

When Flycheck should check syntax automatically.

This variable is a list of events that may trigger syntax checks.
The following events are known:
...
```

Comment: Very reasonable. Unfortunately, and I just edited my question to reflect this, when I use different linters it works fine.

Comment: Actually, it's maybe a good idea to try to disable the checks on the fly so that they're only reloaded on save; then they might not go away.